# find, rounding and daystart

Tags: linux, unix, gnu-coreutils

Suppose a file is created as follows:

```
$ touch -d "00:00:00 today" stamp
```

Why the following command does not find it?

```
$ find -type f -daystart -mtime 0
```

The following command does find this file

```
$ find -type f -daystart -mtime -1
```

Comment: I'm confused by this as well. My first thought was that it was some kind of timezone problem but I haven't been able to get daystart to work correctly either.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug. If you add a file with a non-zero time, say

> $ touch -d "00:00:00.01 today" stamp

It works as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experimentation it looks like Joakim is right - at least for mmin.   daystart seems to be relative from the start of tomorrow.

```
ls -l stamp*
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Jun  7 00:01 stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Jun  7 16:38 stamp2
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Jun  7 16:55 stamp3
```

Notice how stamp3 is at 16:55

60*16 + 55 = 1015

1440 (one day) - 1015 = 425

```
find . -type f -daystart -mmin -425
./stamp3
```

Let's catch stamp2 also

1440 - 60*16 - 38 = 442

```
find . -type f -daystart -mmin -442
./stamp2
./stamp3
```

Now if I want to capture files from a range of times I can do something like this:

```
find . -type f -daystart -mmin -1439 -mmin +425
./stamp2
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like (at least on my machine) `find -daystart` actually searches relative the start of tomorrow.

I find the file when I run `find -daystart -mtime 1` as well as `find -daystart -mmin -1441`  (60*24=1440) but not `find -daystart -mmin -1440`. I can actually find it using exact match with 1441 as well, `find -daystart -mmin 1441`